# Error 500 when preparing a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My registration page shows a Internal server error when submitting the form. There are no errors in the logs but I pinpointed the problem down to this code:

```
    databaseConnectie('database');
    //still works
    $stmt_query = $db->prepare("
      SELECT *
      FROM table
    ");
    //error 500
    //execute would be here
```

I use the same code in other functions which works fine. Privileges also look fine, same as other DBs.

If it helps, I'm running Wordpress with BuddyPress.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: When you get a 500 error, check the error log on the server for the details. There's no way to tell what's wrong from the little snippet you gave.

Comment: If you didn't see errors in the log, you must have been looking in the wrong place. I assure you it will be logged somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

We may not be able to help you out without any more information.
You're saying that you have nothing into the logs, please make sure that debugging is enabled in wp-config.php

Try adding this into the file

`define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);`

and check on your wp-content directory the file 'debug.log'. You should be able to know a bit more about what's happening.